# Zoom on a PictureBox (Windows Mobile)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, picturebox

I'm developing an app for Windows Mobile. I would like to make zoom on a PictureBox's image.

How can I do this?

I think this is more complicated because I'm doing for **Windows Mobile**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all questions that have to do with Windows Mobile are answered with OpenNetCF.
While I haven't tried this, OpenNetCF has a picture box control with a Scale() method.  Perhaps this is what you're looking for.

If you use the [ImageViewer contro](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/20054273-86a5-4125-478c-2480f1f23e12.htm)l, you will get Zoom in/out.